# Copying text from Gmail without line-breaks

Tags: gmail, text, copy-paste

Sending emails in plain text format with Gmail wraps each line at ~70 characters. How can I copy the text from a received/sent mail *without* the line-breaks?

Comment: Based on your comment to your question begs the question what tool do you want to use: notepad, word pad, some Mac text editor,...

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Preferably, I was looking for a way to copy the text 'unwrapped' directly from Gmail, but any tool will do as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I found is to use [TextMate](http://macromates.com/)'s `Unwrap paragraph` function. Copy text from Gmail, paste into TextMate, then go `Text->Unwrap paragraph`.

Comment: Still looking forward to hear if anyone has a more convenient solution

Comment: @Milosz is right, it's okay to ask and answer your own question http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/